# Check attribute presence in XML

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have a PowerPoint VBScript that is trying to check if an XML node contains a certain attribute, before it accesses that attribute.

I can not figure out a way to do that?

My latest attempt is as follows:

```vb
If Not (xNode.Attributes.ItemOf("name") Is Nothing) Then
  winner_str = winner_str & xNode.GetAttribute("name") & " "
End If
```

But this code results in

> Object doesn't support this property or method

What is going wrong here? What can I do to check if an attribute exists in an XML node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're using an `Msxml2.DOMDocument` object for parsing the XML data. The [`Attributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760261.aspx) property returns an [`IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763824.aspx) object, which doesn't have a method `ItemOf()`. Simply use [`GetAttribute()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761380.aspx). The method returns `Null` if the attribute doesn't exist.

```
attr = xNode.GetAttribute("name")
If Not IsNull(attr) Then
  winner_str = winner_str & attr & " "
End If
```